# Fail to cleanup java.sql.Statement on checked Exception

Tags: java, jdbc, findbugs

In my method show below find bug is specifying **Fail to cleanup java.sql.Statement on checked Exception**

```
    public int updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage(String phone, String securityCodeHistoryId, String messageState, String messageId, String parentMessageId)
    {
            CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.error(MODULE+"Start : updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage::"+messageState);
            int result=-1;

        String query=null;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt =null;
        try
        {
            CaptivePortalLogger.sysOut.debug(MODULE + " (Method : isSecurityCodeUsed) Available Connection : "+ CaptivePortalDBConnection.getNumIdleConnections());
            CaptivePortalLogger.sysOut.debug(MODULE + " (Method : isSecurityCodeUsed) Active Connection : "+ CaptivePortalDBConnection.getNumActiveConnections() );

            con = CaptivePortalDBConnection.getDataSource().getConnection();
            CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.error(MODULE+" Before updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage into SendMessageAndReceiveReport: ");              

            query="UPDATE tblsecuritycodehistory SET messagestate = ?,messageid = ? WHERE securitycodehistoryid = ? AND mobileno = ?";

            CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.debug(MODULE + "for updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage in SendMessageAndReceiveReport Query : "+ query);

            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1,messageState); //<b>line 556</b>
            pstmt.setString(2,messageId);
            pstmt.setString(3,securityCodeHistoryId);
            pstmt.setString(4,phone);
            result = pstmt.executeUpdate();

            CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.error(MODULE+" After updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage into SendMessageAndReceiveReport: result::"+result);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            result = -1;
            CaptivePortalLogger.traceLog.debug("Got an exception while updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage in SendMessageAndReceiveReport: ",e);
        }
        finally
        {
            CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.debug(MODULE+"Finally Start");
            try
            {
                if(pstmt!=null)
                    pstmt.close();
                if(con !=null)
                    con.close();

                CaptivePortalLogger.sysOut.debug(MODULE + " (Method : updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage) Closing connections done ....");

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                CaptivePortalLogger.traceLog.debug("Error in closing sqlReader.",e);
            }
        }
    CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.error(MODULE+"End : updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage");
    return result;
}
```

[image: fail to cleanup java.sql.Statement]

I find lots of links on stack but none of them able to solve my problem(may be i m not able to understand them properly). Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance..........

After updaing my finally block with a solution specfied by **@Mark** problem persists

```
finally
{
    CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.debug(MODULE+"Finally Start");
    try {
        if(pstmt!=null)
            pstmt.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Log, ignore, etc
    }
    try {
        if(con !=null)
            con.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Log, ignore, etc
    }
    CaptivePortalLogger.sysOut.debug(MODULE + " (Method : updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage) Closing connections done ....");
}
```

After using @Jon suggestion , my problem get resolved. finally resolved code is ::

```
public int updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage(String phone, String securityCodeHistoryId, String messageState, String messageId, String parentMessageId)
    {
            CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.error(MODULE+"Start : updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage::"+messageState);
            int result=-1;
            String query=null;
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt =null;
            try
            {
                CaptivePortalLogger.sysOut.debug(MODULE + " (Method : isSecurityCodeUsed) Available Connection : "+ CaptivePortalDBConnection.getNumIdleConnections());
                CaptivePortalLogger.sysOut.debug(MODULE + " (Method : isSecurityCodeUsed) Active Connection : "+ CaptivePortalDBConnection.getNumActiveConnections() );

                con = CaptivePortalDBConnection.getDataSource().getConnection();
                CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.error(MODULE+" Before updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage into SendMessageAndReceiveReport: ");              

                query="UPDATE tblsecuritycodehistory SET messagestate = ?,messageid = ? WHERE securitycodehistoryid = ? AND mobileno = ?";

                CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.debug(MODULE + "for updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage in SendMessageAndReceiveReport Query : "+ query);
                try
                {
                    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    pstmt.setString(1,messageState);
                    pstmt.setString(2,messageId);
                    pstmt.setString(3,securityCodeHistoryId);
                    pstmt.setString(4,phone);
                    result = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                }
                catch(SQLException e1)
                {
                    CaptivePortalLogger.traceLog.debug("Error in closing sqlReader.",e1);
                }
                finally{
                    if(pstmt!=null)
                    pstmt.close();
                }

                CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.error(MODULE+" After updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage into SendMessageAndReceiveReport: result::"+result);
            }
            catch (SQLException e2) {
                result = -1;
                CaptivePortalLogger.traceLog.debug("Got an exception while updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage in SendMessageAndReceiveReport: ",e2);
            }
            finally
            {
                CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.debug(MODULE+"Finally Start");
                try
                {
                    if(con !=null)
                        con.close();

                    CaptivePortalLogger.sysOut.debug(MODULE + " (Method : updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage) Closing connections done ....");

                }
                catch(SQLException e)
                {
                    CaptivePortalLogger.traceLog.debug("Error in closing sqlReader.",e);
                }
            }
        CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.error(MODULE+"End : updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage");
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You talk about Firebug finding this - are you sure you don't mean FindBugs? The only Firebug I'm aware of is a client-side web development tool.

Comment: Sorry Jon for misguiding, actually its findbug, i have update now.(thanks for correcting me)

Comment: @Jon i have now mentioned the changed code of finally block.

Comment: You're still only using a single `finally` block. That's not what my answer suggested: "you should have a separate try/finally block for each resource". See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
if(pstmt!=null)
    pstmt.close();
if(con !=null)
    con.close();
```

Now consider that `pstmt.close()` can throw an exception... which means `con.close()` wouldn't be called.

If you're using Java 7, use a try-with-resources statement instead, but otherwise you should have a separate try/finally block for each resource.

```
try {
   connection = ...;
   try {
      statement = ...;
   } finally {
      // Clean up statement
   }
} finally {
   // Clean up connection
}
```

I'd also *strongly* recommend against catching blanket `Exception` - it's better to catch *specific* exceptions which you can actually handle, and let other exceptions propagate up the stack. Also, you appear to be using integer values to signal success or failure of your method - that's not idiomatic Java; exceptions are preferred for error handling, in general.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the issue, but is their any way to resolve it, as i tried to use the solutions specified in other answers but still issue persists.

Comment: It worked Jon ...  Thank you. but one thing is that why findbug gives error if i specified them in single finally block becoz that block will always executed. than why two different finally blocks

Comment: @Prateek: No, you're catching `Exception` in your "single finally block" attempt - but other `Throwable` values could be thrown, in which case you still wouldn't be cleaning up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if `pstmt.close()` throws an Exception, then the connection is never closed.

Either do not close the statement in the finally (as drivers are required to close `Statement` objects if the `Connection` is closed), or put both in their own `try..catch`-block. Eg:

```
finally
{
    CaptivePortalLogger.appLog.debug(MODULE+"Finally Start");
    try {
        if(pstmt!=null)
            pstmt.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Log, ignore, etc
    }
    try {
        if(con !=null)
            con.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Log, ignore, etc
    }
    CaptivePortalLogger.sysOut.debug(MODULE + " (Method : updateSecurityCodeHistoryForMessage) Closing connections done ....");
}
```

Comment: I used this one too, still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is correct.

You should close all your SQL resources in a finally block, using *individually* wrapped calls to close methods.

You can do it with a utility class:

```
package persistence;

public class DatabaseUtils {
    // similar methods for ResultSet and Connection
    public static void close(Statement s) {
        try {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // Log the exception
        }       
    }
}
```

Call the close method in a finally block in the method that created the resource.

Comment: i closed them in finally block in individual try- catch but still the issue is same.i hope your saying the same thing

Comment: Nope, yours is different.  Both are in the same try/catch block.  What if the first one throws an exception?  The second one will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cleanup /close resource in separate try/catch/finally block otherwise if any one throw an exception then rest of will be remain unclosed.